# empty array $_FILES after redirect by header

Tags: php, forms, file

I send files by my form. I send form to action A, but in action A i use function `header()` to action B. I use function `header()` so my array`$_FILES` in action B is empty. Is any possibilities to have date in `$_FILES`

Comment: `$_FILES` is only populated when the form upload is completed. Once you redirect that process is over and forgotten. You need to work with your file upload before redirecting.

Comment: For $_FILES you need to store the value in A.php and redirected to B.php else the value of the $_FILES will be lost

Answer (score 2):

Short answer no

When using a header('location: b.php'); you send the header back to the client and the client send a second request to the b.php url.

You need to store the file within you A.php file and then redirect to b.php.

You can add a parameter to that url (example: `header('location: b.php?file=ok');`), or store the information in session to know that a file has been submited.